# 一週間続いたあなた パワーアップ -1.2kcal

Tags: sentence

The second step of these stairs has a sticker that reads:

> 一週間続いたあなた パワーアップ -1.2kcal

What does it mean?

In particular, are "パワーアップ" and "-1.2kcal" parts of a sentence, and if yes how does "-1.2kcal" relate to "一週間"?

*Note: I am not talking about the veracity of the claim, but strictly about the semantic meaning of this sign, how it is expected to be understood.*

[image]

Comment: １週間続けると「パワーアップ」、1か月間は「シェープアップ」。２段毎に0.2kcal減っているので、1週間＝-1.2kcalじゃなさそうだね。何段でどれくらいkcalを燃やしているかの目安だけのようです。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-1.2kcal` and such refer to the amount of calorie you have consumed. Some long stairs have similar signs. It's not grammatically related to the sentence on the left.

Since this is a message from the train operator, I think this is supposed to encourage passengers to use stairs instead of crowded escalators/elevators. It means "If you have used these stairs for one week, you are (already a little) stronger!".

「一か月で実感！シェイプアップ」 is similar, "If you have used these stairs for a month, you'll realize you have become slimmer!"